# Is there any master/detail best practice to limit detail lookups when quickly enumerating master records

Tags: master-detail

Currently we have master/detail solution which creates requests on detail each time you select master record. When you go through master records fast, there is bunch of requests on irrelevant details. The only relevant one is on the end of queue.
Is there any best practice to use to postpone service calls in this fast result browsing scenario?